# Error in set-pnplistitem when passing an array of managed metadata terms

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

using pnp powershell to modify sharepoint online list items, i'm trying to update an existing list item, adding an array of managed metadata terms, but the command keeps failing when I try to update the entry with more than one term. Or, if I pass an array variable with a single term.

```
set-pnplistitem -list "Pages" -Identity $itemID -values @{"Category"=("How-To")} -SystemUpdate #WORKS
set-pnplistitem -list "Pages" -Identity $itemID -values @{"Category"=("For Teams That Create Digital Content")} -SystemUpdate #WORKS
set-pnplistitem -list "Pages" -Identity $itemID -values @{"Category"=("How-To","For Teams That Create Digital Content")} -systemUpdate #FAILS
$test=@("How-To")
set-pnplistitem -list "Pages" -Identity $itemID -values @{"Category"=$test} -SystemUpdate # FAILS
$test=@("How-To","For Teams That Create Digital Content")
set-pnplistitem -list "Pages" -Identity $itemID -values @{"Category"=$test} -SystemUpdate # FAILS

error:
set-pnplistitem : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At C:\Powershell\test.ps1:120 char:13
+             set-pnplistitem -list "Pages" -Identity $itemID -va ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Set-PnPListItem], NullReferenceException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.SetListItem
```

Am I doing this wrong, or is there a bug in set-pnpListItem ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps#optional-parameters Maybe certain items don't accept arrays? Do you need an array, or could you pass a multiline string instead?

Comment: That documentation page shows the same syntax as the third line in my example - maybe that tells me all I need to know - that it is a bug?

Comment: My thought was perhaps there is validation on the property name, and certain properties cannot bind to certain values. So, for instance, perhaps you could only map to a single category, but could have multiple of a different property.